# Add unicode characters as part of label in Winforms with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, special-characters

I want to change a `label.Text` to be: "This " + [[this sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f514/browsertest.htm)] + "sign", but when I'm doing that the sign won't display correctly.

Comment: show the code. We dont know what u r doing ??

Comment: lblMonth.Text = "This  sign";

Comment: Are you sure you have a font that supports this character? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f514/fontsupport.htm

Comment: Oh, that must be it. But is it possible to change the font for just that sign in the lable?

Comment: Segoe UI Symbol seems to work, but I can't figure out how to just change the font for that sign, and not for the rest of the lable.

Comment: Oh... Not in a ListView too i suppose? That's too bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# text is Unicode, so the problem won't be that the character cannot be encoded properly. Therefore the most plausible explanation is that the font you use does not contain a glyph for this character. The solution will therefore be to use a font that does.